# Can I make the entry of objects in Excel a little more dynamic?

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub codalScraping()

Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim ht As HTMLDocument
Dim link As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim x As Integer

link = InputBox("link", , "codal.ir/...")
i = 1
'x = 0

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.navigate (link)
    Do Until ie.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop
Set ht = ie.document
Set elems = ht.getElementsByClassName("rayanDynamicStatement")(0).getElementsByTagName("tr")
    For Each elem In elems
    With avtivesheet
    Sheet1.Range("A" & i) = elem.Children(x).textContent
    'Sheet1.Range("B" & i) = elem.Children(1).textContent
    'Sheet1.Range("C" & i) = elem.Children(2).textContent
    'Sheet1.Range("D" & i) = elem.Children(3).textContent
    'Sheet1.Range("E" & i) = elem.Children(4).textContent
    i = i + 1
    x = x + 1
    End With
    Next elem
End Sub
```

I want the number of rows to change according to the number of objects and I do not need to hit "ABCD..." by myself

thanks a lot

Comment: Use Celles instead of  Range like:  Sheet1.Cells(i, 1).Value = elem.Children(x).textContent

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First, to make this dynamic, it helps to be able to save values into an array using a loop instead of one line of code per value.

Then, you put the array into a range and VBA will automatically put each element of the array into a corresponding cells in the range. Like a 2x2 array onto a 2x2 range will put each array element into a cell intuitively. You can also use the dimensions of the array to determine the size of the range that you need to output all of the values.

For your code:

```vb
    Dim chldTxt() As String
    ReDim chldTxt(0 To elem.Children.Count - 1)
    For x = 0 To elem.Children.Count - 1
        chldTxt(x) = elem.Children(x).textContent
    Next x
    
    Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Resize(1, elem.Children.Count - 1) = chldTxt
```

Comment: i have ran this and received "object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: @bobbysands on which line and for which property?